# Check in C source if .ko object has been insmoded

Tags: linux-device-driver

Is there any inbuilt function by which can I check in my source that a specific kernel object

file has already been insmoded ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to do this in kernel space. If so, check out 
kernel/module.c: find_module(char *name)